# Rails: how to update HABTM checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am following `railscast 17-- HABTM checkbox` to add attribute to my user model.

```
   <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[role_group_ids][]',nil %>
     <%  RoleGroup.all.each do |role_group|%>
     <%= check_box_tag 'user[role_group_ids][]',role_group.id,
       @user.role_group_ids.include?(role_group.id) %>
     <%= role_group.name %><br>
   <% end %>
```

In the update action, if I update all attributes like this, everything is ok.

```
  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.update(user_params) 
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, role_group_ids:[])
  end
```

But I just want to update the value of checkboxes instead of all attributes, I tried this, however it did not work.

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:role_group_ids, user[role_group_ids])
  end
```

Anybody could tell me how to fix this?

=================update===============

```
  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @user.update(user_params.slice(:role_group_ids))
    puts '====================='
    puts user_params.slice(:role_group_ids)
    puts '====================='
  end
```

this can not update either, the output like this

```
=====================
#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007faae0656c50>
=====================
```

Comment: Where is `@oms_user` defined? Can you also post the log details when you make your request to update? I'd like to see what params are passed and what ActiveRecord is doing.

Comment: @luckyruby  that is my mistake, just #user, please see updated code

Comment: Can you post the log details?

Comment: @luckyruby I think it is not correct to update the user data, because user table do not have role_group_id, this field exists in the join table called user_role_group. Two fields role_group_id and user_id in the join table. But for now I have no idea about how to update the data in the join table, could you help?

Comment: I can't help without the log details so I can see what's being passed in and what rails is doing in activerecord when you call update.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@user.update(user_params.slice(:role_group_ids))`

Comment: Hi, the second edition not work either, please see my updated information.